# The main difference between Superscalar and Parallelism

Tags: cpu, computer-architecture, cpu-architecture, parallel-processing

In superscalar processing, more than one instruction is executed in parallel at each core, so how would that differ from parallel processing then?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Superscalar is a term that refers to the architecture of a CPU or single core.

To execute an instruction, a CPU has to perform a number of steps, and each step is handled by a specific dedicated part or "execution unit" of the CPU.  Non-superscalar CPUs start from step 0 to X (X can vary depending on the type of instruction) and finish all the steps completely before starting the next instruction.

Superscalar CPUs will try to get new instructions in the "pipeline" at step 0 for example, before the previous instruction has completed all its steps.  So the CPU is more fully utilized and faster (and much more complex) because its execution units are always working.

A workload achieves parallelism if it can be divided into units such that more than one of something can work on it effectively.  Superscalar architectures attempt to parallelize  executing a single instruction stream in a single core/CPU.

Parallel processing is similar in concept, but we are not talking about a CPU's instruction stream anymore, but rather some (likely big) set of data that needs to be processed.  How can you split the workload where X amount of CPUs or even separate nodes connected by a network, running the same or different programs, such that the workload is processed most efficiently?  What is needed to ensure the CPUs or systems don't step on each other and corrupt data?  That's the type of questions parallel processing asks.

Comment: I'm not sure this answer is correct. What you are describing is "pipelining", but according to the [wikipedia page on superscalar processors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscalar_processor) these are different technologies: *"While a superscalar CPU is typically also pipelined, superscalar and pipelining execution are considered different performance enhancement techniques."*.

Comment: @PierU You might be right.  Maybe things like SIMD are more what paralellism is - explicitly saying you can do multiple X at once, whereas superscalar is like "let's try to keep all the execution units as full as possible, but no guarantees"

Answer (score 2):

A superscalar architecture is just one kind of parallelism among many. The [wikipedia page on superscalar processors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscalar_processor) explains it quite well.

A superscalar processor can start 2 (or more) instructions in parallel, which means that it has multiple physical execution units. This kind of parallelism is entirely managed by the hardware, at the processor level: the processor fetches the instructions and decides on its own which ones can be start simultaneously (and possibly out of order). The compilers do not have to generate a specific binary code.

This is different from for instance the multicore/multithread parallelism, which is managed at the software level: the compiler has to create several execution threads, which are possibly executed on different cores/different CPUs. In contrast the superscalar parallelism works inside a core, but this is not exclusive: a CPU can be multicore, each core having a superscalar architecture.

Pipelining, as described in the other answer is also a kind of parallelism that is entirely managed a the hardware level: only one instruction can start at a time, but the next instruction can start before the previous one has completed.

Many processors have also vector capabilities, which is SIMD parallelism (Single Intruction, Multiple Data): the processor has vector registers where it can load several variables (typically 4, 8,...) instead of one for usual registers, and vector instructions to apply the same operation (an addition, a multiplication...) simultaneously to all the variables of the register. Here, the compiler has to generate a binary that explicitely contains these instructions.